# What decides number of mappers and reducers of an operation in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am reading https://0x0fff.com/spark-architecture-shuffle/, the articles talks about number of files getting generated based on number of mappers and reducers tasks.

But I am not sure what decides number of mappers and reducers tasks.

Could you please help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your data is partitioned. In Spark SQL, when you read data from the source the number of partitions will depend on the size of your dataset, number of input files and on the number of cores that you have available. Spark will determine how many partitions should be created and so in the first stage of your job this will be the number of 'mappers tasks'. Then if you perform transformation that induces shuffle (like groupBy, join, dropDuplicates, ...), the number of 'reducers tasks' will be 200 by default, because Spark will create 200 partitions. You can change that by this setting:

```
sparkSession.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", n)
```

where *n* is the number of partitions that you want to use (number of tasks that you want to have after each shuffle). [Here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#other-configuration-options) is a link to configuration options in Spark documentation which mentions this setting.